# Почему нет тегов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, профиль-участника

Хотелось бы видеть в списке ответов под названием вопроса теги. Как минимум, я бы находил бы нужный мне ответ намного быстрее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Идея интересная. Но лучше на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) такое предлагать.

Comment: @Suvitruf продублировать? Или возможен перенос) Хотя русский язык..

Comment: Продублировать)

Comment: Лучше в результатах поиска.

Comment: как по мне это лишнее... можно ткнуть по своей метке и отфильтровать вопрос если нужно...да и в поиске расширенном можно и пользователя и метку задать

Comment: по опыту могу сказать что официально никто такого не сделает в ближайшие годы, но вы можете сами для себя лично написать userscript чтобы он подгружал динамически теги, только не забудьте использовать API а не тупо страницы грузить, а то коммьюнити менеджеры предупреждали что от этого могут аккаунт пометить как спамерский или что-то такое, в общем поговорите с опытными userscript писателями если сами не уверены в своих силах

Comment: @user1306322 А где доки по `API`

Comment: @doox911 https://api.stackexchange.com/docs а примеры скриптов можете посмотреть на https://stackapps.com/ только там могут быть как раз плохие примеры, так что осторожнее :)

Comment: Если напишете скрипт, запостите его пожалуйста на StackApps и оставьте ответ здесь со ссылкой на него чтобы другие тоже могли им воспользоваться или даже улучшить

Comment: @user1306322 Спсаибо. Обязательно попробую.

Answer (score 8):

А мне бы не хотелось загромождать список ответов метками.

А вот в списке [результатов поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aa) они были бы вполне кстати.

Comment: Галочку можно добавить — показывать да/нет (про ЛК)

Comment: а зачем они там? если нужны ответы по тэгу, то просто тэг в поисковый запрос.

Comment: @teran, ну для вопросов-то они там есть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bUH7.png. даже в смешанном поиске у вопросов они есть, а у ответов нет: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r4af.png. Мне кажется, было бы удобно иметь и там и там.